# Is there a possibility to make from one long column two small in R?

Tags: r

Hope you have a nice day.

Today I was trying two make from one big column two small ones in R. However, I haven't found a way how to make it.

I have something like this (however, it is way bigger)

```
name3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
df1 <- data.frame(name3)
print(df1)
```

I want to do something like this. My intention is just take the total number of variables and divide it into two equal groups.

```
 name <- c(1, 2, 3)
 name1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
 df <- data.frame(name, name1)  
 print (df)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the number of elements always even? What would you like in case it’s not?

Comment: Yes, the number is always even (576).
Thank you for the prompt reply!

Comment: `head(df, nrow(df)/2)` for first half, and `tail` instead of `head` for the remaining half.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, you can first write this as a matrix in which you specify the number of columns
than transform the matrix to dataframe

from a dataframe you can convert each column to a vector

This is how I did it

```
name3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(name3, ncol = 2))

name1 <- df$V1
name2 <- df$V2
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to accomplish this as close to base `r` as possible, this would be my method if the order of the sub vector don't matter:

```
# needed for index function
library(zoo) 

# simple function to calculate even / odd
is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0

# define my vector of values
name3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# split vector by even or odd index. 
split(name3,f= is.even(index(name3)) )
```

Result:

```
$`FALSE`
[1] 1 3 5

$`TRUE`
[1] 2 4 6
```